# How do I remove this div from the dom?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how do I remove the #hello div below and just keep the `a` element within the outer div tags?

I want to go from this:

```
<div>
  <div id="hello">
    <a href="http://google.com"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the unwrap function:

```
$('#hello a').unwrap();
```

See http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/.  Cheers!

Comment: He might be waiting for super perfect, I up voted you anyway :)

Comment: Just did, it made me wait. Then I forgot about it for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

```
var divToBeRemoved=$("#hello");
var html=divToBeRemoved.html();
var parentOfDiv=divToBeRemoved.parent();
divToBeRemoved.remove();
parentOfDiv.html(html);
```

Comment: you have a typo "divToRemoved", second line (:

Answer (score 0):

```
var alink = $('#hello a').clone();
$('#hello').parent().html(alink);
```